# Trying to replace parts of string start with same search chars

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I'm trying to replace parts of my string. But I met a problem when my search string start with same character:

```
$string = "Good one :y. Keep going :y2"; 

$str = str_replace(array_keys($my_array), array_values($my_array), $string);   
$my_array= array(":y" => "a", ":y2" => "b");
```

ouput:

```
Good one a. Keep going a2
```

I need my `str_replace()` to match the word correctly/exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides that you should define your array first before you use it, this should work for you:

```
$str = strtr($string, $my_array);
```

Your problem is that [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) goes through the entire string and replaces everything it can, you can also see this in the manual.

And a quote from there:

> Because str_replace() replaces **left to right**, it **might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacement**s. See also the examples in this document.

So for this I used [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) here, because it tries to match the longest byte in the search first.

You can also read this in the manual and a quote from there:

> If given two arguments, the second should be an array in the form array('from' => 'to', ...). The return value is a string where all the occurrences of the array keys have been replaced by the corresponding values. **The longest keys will be tried first. Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.**

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace first for `:y2` and then for `:y`

```
$string = "Good one :y. Keep going :y2"; 

$my_array= array(":y2" => "b", ":y" => "a");

$str = str_replace(array_keys($my_array), array_values($my_array), $string);
```

outputs

```
Good one a. Keep going b
```

[Try it](https://eval.in/304296)

Comment: You have the right thoughts, but you used the wrong function :) Here you almost do an implementation of `strtr()`, but you can't quite do it with `str_replace()`. Here you also start with the longest byte replacements, but you still would replace previous replacements which you wouldn't do with `strtr()`. (E.g. if you replace: `:y2` with `:y` you would end up with `a a`, but with `strtr()` you would have `a :y`)

Comment: Yeah well I didn't know that function, I always used str_replace to do this knida job. Happy to have learnt something new

Answer (score 0):

```
:y\b
```

Use this to replace only `:y` and not `:y2`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/9

```
$re = "":y\\b"m";
$str = "Good one :y. Keep going :y2\n";
$subst = "a";


$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Similarly for `:y2` use `:y2\b`.