# preg_replace reverse/mutual replacing on synonyms words

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, str-replace, preg-replace-callback

I want to mutual or reverse replace on synonyms words. I have to give an example to tell you:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
$find = array('/ipsum/', '/amet/');
$replace = array('amet', 'ipsum');
$output = preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

#### Output is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ipsum, consectetur adipiscing elit

#### Expected output is should be like that:

> Lorem amet dolor sit ipsum, consectetur adipiscing elit

So i want to change all `ipsum` to `amet` and `amet` to `lorem`. These two words that "ipsum" and "amet" just samples. I have thousands synonyms words.

Like you see, i tried `preg_replace` function but doest work.

Comment: Do you have only static strings to replace, rather than potentially dynamic patterns necessitating regex?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski static strings that stored database.

Comment: You are [probably looking for this solution then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251248/trying-to-replace-parts-of-string-start-with-same-search-chars) using `strtr()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `strtr`:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
$find = array('ipsum', 'amet');
$replace = array('amet', 'ipsum');
$trans = array_combine($find, $replace);

$result = strtr($string, $trans);
```

The main difference with `str_replace` is that string is parsed only once, when `str_replace` (or `preg_replace`) parses it once for each item.

Not very interesting for you example but you can do it to with `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$trans = ['ipsum' => 'amet', 'amet'=>'ipsum'];
$result = preg_replace_callback('~amet|ipsum~', function ($m) use ($trans) {
    return $trans[$m[0]]; }, $string);
```

If you want to achieve the same with `str_replace` or `preg_replace` you need to use a placeholder:

```
$find = ['ipsum', 'amet', '###placeholder###'];
$replace = ['###placeholder###', 'ipsum', 'amet'];
$result = str_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: Working perfect but i need to match only word. Doest work with this string `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ipsumed adipiscing elit` because of `ipsumed` words will replaced `ameted`. I can exact match with `preg_replace`, so with `strtr`()`?

Comment: @Bora: use the `preg_replace_callback` or `preg_replace` methods with word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for three solutions, all great works! I need to exact match word(s).

Comment: With `preg_replace_callback` and `\b` word boundry great works now, really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would call a [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) like this

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
$reverse = preg_replace_callback('/\b(ipsum|amet)\b/', function($matches) {
    return $matches[0] == 'ipsum' ? 'amet' : 'ipsum';
}, $string);
//Lorem amet dolor sit ipsum, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

> Use word boundary (`\b`) around, if you want to match exact word only.